# Responsive Content+Sidebar: min-width for sidebar breaks in new line

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a problem with my testing responsive design.

The sidebar never should break in the next line if min-width is reached. (overflow/scrollbar is fine if the resolution is under 600px)

The code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  min-width: 150px;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    min-widht <br>
    sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

(open in full window)

The Sidebar has min-width (in need this min-width to ensure the content will be display nice). Instead should get smaller the content. It works until a particular resolution / resizing and then breaks.

fyi: please no JS solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with flexbox:

- You can avoid the clear fixes
- Parent container doesn't consider child's dimensions when floating

Snippet below (additions commented):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  /* set flex on parent */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
/* .wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
} */

.content {
  /* float: left; */
  width: 75%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.sidebar {
  /* float: right; */
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  min-width: 150px;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    min-widht
    <br>sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works perfect! just for completion: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox
(the clearfix was for special thing in my code, but thanks for the hint :))